# Add more data to barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

There are a dataframe :

```
{'Date': {0: '2020-06-01',
  1: '2020-06-02',
  2: '2020-06-03',
  3: '2020-06-04',
  4: '2020-06-08'},
 'Started': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'Ended': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'conversion': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.67, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.5}}
```

I'm visualizate it by  `data2.set_index('Date').plot.bar(figsize = (25, 20))` in JupiterNotebook

But i also need to add data from column 'conversion' under 'date' or maybe over columns. It is not necessary to do it in my way, maybe use seaborn or etc

[image: barplot]

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) returns [matplotlib.axes.Axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) object. You can draw plot on it like `ax.plot()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [vignette for annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/annotation_demo.html) in matplotlib. For placing the annotation on top of the bars, you can calculate the maximum height of each x-axis entry and use annotate (the default settings is `textcoords='data'`):

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2020-06-01',
  1: '2020-06-02',
  2: '2020-06-03',
  3: '2020-06-04',
  4: '2020-06-08'},
 'Started': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'Ended': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'conversion': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.67, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.5}})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
data2.set_index('Date').plot.bar(ax=ax)
hts = data2.iloc[:,1:].apply(max,axis=1) - 0.05
for i in range(len(hts)):
    ax.text(i,hts[i],data2['conversion'][i])
```

[image]

To annotate under the x-axis, you do something similar, just that you need to transform the x-axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
data2.set_index('Date').plot.bar(ax=ax)
for i in range(len(hts)):
    ax.annotate(data2['conversion'][i],xy=(i,-0.6),
                xycoords=ax.get_xaxis_transform(),color="blue")
```

[image]